# Pressure tensor in brownian dynamics

Tags: pressure, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics, brownian-motion

I need to calculate the pressure autocorrelation function in a Brownian dynamics particle simulation to get the viscosity (which is proportional to the time integral of this function):
$$ \left \langle \sum_{x<y} P_{xy} (t) P_{xy} (0) \right \rangle $$
The pressure is defined as:
$$ P_{xy} = \frac{1}{V} \left[ \sum_{j} m_j v_{jx} v_{jy} + 0.5 \sum_{i \neq j} r_{ijx} f_{ijy} \right] $$
my problem is that in a Brownian simulation I don't have the access to the velocity, which appears in the pressure definition, because I neglect the acceleration term in the Langevin equation. Are there any references of how to deal with this problem and calculate pressure tensor without velocity?
The equations I wrote are from Rapaport's book.

Comment: Here they put velocities to zero:
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/la063210j